# Как проверить в юнит-тестах в Django, что в контексте ответа тот же заказ, который был создан перед тестом?

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты

Напишите тест для `OrderDetailView`.

Объявите класс тестов `OrderDetailViewTestCase`.
В `setUpClass` создайте пользователя и добавьте пользователю необходимые разрешения для просмотра заказа (“shopapp.view_order”).

Добавьте удаление пользователя в `tearDownClass`.
При помощи метода `setUp` сделайте вход пользователя и создание заказа для дальнейшего теста.

В методе `tearDown` сделайте удаление заказа.
Объявите метод `test_order_details` для проверки получения заказа:

- убедитесь, что в теле ответа есть адрес заказа;
- убедитесь, что в теле ответа есть промокод;
- убедитесь, что в контексте ответа тот же заказ, который был создан перед тестом (сравните по первичному ключу).

Это models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    delivery_address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    promocode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="orders")
```

Это views.py:

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = (
        Order.objects
        .select_related("user")
        .prefetch_related("products")
    )
```

Это tests.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Order


class OrderDetailViewTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.user = User.objects.create(username='test', password='qwerty')
        permission_order = Permission.objects.get(codename='view_order')
        cls.user.user_permissions.add(permission_order)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.user.delete()

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        self.order = Order.objects.create(
            delivery_address='ul Verona, d 13',
            promocode='SALE_123',
            user=self.user)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.order.delete()

    def test_order_details(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse(
            'shopapp:order_details',
            kwargs={'pk': self.order.pk})
        )
        self.assertContains(response, self.order.delivery_address)
        self.assertContains(response, self.order.promocode)
```

Не знаю, как проверить, что в контексте ответа тот же заказ, который был создан перед тестом. Прошу помощи

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, актуален ли еще вопрос, но сам столкнулся с такой задачкой и потому делюсь решением.

Для начала нужно обратиться к контексту ответа, так как это `TemplateResponse`, чтобы получить первичный ключ созданного объекта (заказа) и сохранить в переменную:

```
received_data = response.context["order"].pk
```

В другой переменной сохранить ожидаемую инфу по первичному ключу заказа, который создавался в тесте:

```
expected_data = self.order.pk
```

Ну и в конце, просто сравнить ключи:

```
self.assertEqual(received_data, expected_data)
```

Comment: Спасибо за то, что поделились вариантом решения! Я тоже нашла решение. Оно немного отличается, но суть такая же. В setUp дописала добавление продукта в заказ `self.order.products.add(self.products)`, а в тестах - сравнила контекст ответа с объектом order: `self.assertEqual(response.context['object'], self.order)`